# Receive broadcast for activity not started yet?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I want to have a `Broadcast Receiver` to obtain location information for an activity that is not started yet. Basically I have some location that I obtain in one activity. When I click my FAB button, I want to take the location that I obtained in the first activity and send it over to the activity that the FAB button navigates to so I can use the location in that activity. Here is my attempt:

LocationServices.java: This is where my `location` is received and the broadcasted.

```
  @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location.hasAccuracy()) {
            if (location.getAccuracy() < 30) {
                locationUpdateListener.updateLocation(location);
                Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(LocationService.ACTION_LOCATION);
                broadcastIntent.putExtra("latitude", location.getLatitude());
                broadcastIntent.putExtra("longitude", location.getLongitude());
                activity.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
            }
        }
    }
```

CreatePost.java: Here is where I want to ideally grab the location that was Broadcasted and use it in this file but the `onReceive` is never called. The activity is instantiated when the user clicks on the FAB button.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    locationReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            try {
                if(location == null) {
                    location = new Location("Provider");
                }
                location.setLatitude(intent.getDoubleExtra("latitude", 0.0));
                location.setLongitude(intent.getDoubleExtra("longitude", 0.0));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };
    registerReceiver(locationReceiver, new IntentFilter(LocationService.ACTION_LOCATION));
}
```

Is there any way to send the `location` over when the activity is instantiated? Or am I not understanding the idea of a `Broadcast Receiver` correctly?

Comment: How do you start the second activity? Can we see the code? Instead of sending a broadcast, u can send the latitude and longitude when u start it first

Comment: You can put the data in the intent that starts the second activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the data in the Intent that starts the second activity. Then in the second activity, get the intent by calling getIntent(), and retrieve data from it. Something like this:

Pass the location details by

```
private void startActivityWithData() {
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra("latitude", location.getLatitude());
     intent.putExtra("longitude", location.getLongitude());
     startActivity(intent);
}
```

And receive the Location details on the `SecondActivity` by

```
class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        float latitude = intent.getFloatExtra("latitude", 0);
        float longitude = intent.getFloatExtra("longitude", 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to call register receiver onResume.You can use also this way.

If you need to use Receiver onResume then need to unregister onPause.

And please check your locationchanged is working properly.

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Location newLocation;

private BroadcastReceiver coordinateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {
        newLocation.setLatitude(intent.getDoubleExtra("latitude", 0.0));
        newLocation.setLongitude(intent.getDoubleExtra("longitude", 0.0));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);
    registerReceiver(coordinateReceiver, new IntentFilter(LocationService.ACTION_LOCATION));

}


 @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    try {
         unregisterReceiver(coordinateReceiver);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: I don't think you are answering the question here. How are you sending that info the second activity. Also, You should be calling `unregisterReceiver()` in `onPause()`. `onDestroy()` should not be used to call that or to save any data. Read this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()

Comment: For sure. I tried your implementation above but for whatever reason it's still not working for me. `onReceive` is never called after `LocationService` class calls the `onLocationChanged` function

Comment: @th3pat3l i already mention in my answer about onPause and onresume.He is broadcasting location onLocationChanged that is fine.But not able to get location in other class.So, i just give example.

Comment: @Saveen but his problem is the `BroadcastReceiver` is not registered when he is sending broadcast. Broadcast method can't work here

Comment: @user1871869 implementation is fine.Its working try to debug your code.Is there something is missing. or you can try with event bus to send location.

Comment: @th3pat3l i have register it on **oncreate** please check.

Comment: @Saveen but `onCreate()` gets called AFTER you send the broadcast because that is `onCreate()` of the second activity. `onLocationChanged()` is in the first activity. So location will come. Broadcast will send but there is no one to listen it yet cause 2nd activity `onCreate()` isn't called yet

Comment: Location will receive after register the receiver.

Comment: That's not how Broadcast works. Receiver has to be registered and someone has to be "listening". wrkwrk just posted the right way to send the data to the second activity

Comment: I know how to work broadcst.If activity is not init then whats the reason he need location in that activity. If activity is init then broadcast register in that activity.So, he can able to get location in particular activity.

Comment: I have done same thing and thats work fine.There is no such problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your scenario correctly as I can't see the whole structure.

First of all, you can only receive a broadcast intent when you registered the receiver properly. For that you have two options: a *static* and *dynamic* way.

You did that correctly in your `onResume()` method. This should work as long as the application is running, which called/registered the receiver.

If you want a more permanent solution, you should register it in a static way inside your *AndroidManifest.xml*. By doing that, the Android system knows that your app contains a broadcast receiver for the location data and can deliver the intent. So even after you reboot your device, the receiver is still working. The only thing required is, you already started the app containing the broadcast receiver at least once.

This is what you have to put into your AndroidManifest.xml inside the `<application>` element (of course, you have to replace the `com.your.example.ACTION_LOCATION` with your string accordingly).

```
<receiver android:name=".LocationBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.your.example.ACTION_LOCATION" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Since you explicitly specify `LocationBroadcastReceiver` in your manifest, you have to create the corresponding class too:

```
public class LocationBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
               // your code when intent is received
        }
}
```

If you do it this way, you no longer have to register the receiver in your code and you also don't have to create an instance of `LocationBroadcastReceiver` manually.

For more details on this, see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).